# How to merge columns into one which has missing values in BigQuery Sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have multiple columns with missing values, if one column is null then the value would be in any one of the other 3 columns, how can I make single column by merging columns into one in BigQuery SQL.

Please see the attached image, Thank you in Advance.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QY2Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need something like:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable 
SET value1 = COALESCE(value2, value3)
WHERE value1 IS NULL
```

See documentation of [COALESCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional_expressions)

Comment: Thank you Yun, Let me check that one.